# Startup logo has not changed since I removed KDE

Tags: boot, kde, desktop-environments

I installed KDE on Ubuntu 16.04, but after some time I removed it because it was slow, but although I've removed it, my startup logo is still Kubuntu not Ubuntu!

How can I make it turn back to the Ubuntu logo?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

you can switch between the logos. Just enter the number corresponding to the logo you want.

The Ubuntu one was installed automatically so you should be able to select it.

Afterwards run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: thanks but i use this code before and this code just changed shutdown logo .but startup logo is  still kubuntu